# Vagrant NFS woes

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

Given the following Vagrntfile:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.gui = true
    vb.memory = 4000
    vb.cpus = 2
  end

## hold of on these - not sure why but they don't seem to work

  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.0.103"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant/", type: "nfs"

  ## forward web
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080

  ## forward API
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 1337, host: 1337

  ## forward SignalR
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 1338, host: 1338

  config.vm.box_download_insecure = true

  config.vm.box = "box-cutter/ubuntu1404-desktop"


end
```

Why oh why do I keep getting:

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -o 'vers=3,udp' 192.168.0.1:'/Users/wayne/sonatribe' /vagrant

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.0.1:/Users/wayne/sonatribe
```

HELP!!!

[UPDATE]

Output after changing NFS line to

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :nfs => { :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=777"] }
```

Yields the following:

```
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Installing NFS client...
==> default: Exporting NFS shared folders...
==> default: Preparing to edit /etc/exports. Administrator privileges will be required...
==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -o 'vers=3,udp' 192.168.0.1:'/Users/wayne/sonatribe' /vagrant

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.0.1:/Users/wayne/sonatribe
```

[UPDATE 2]
My customised base box is:

config.vm.box = "XUbuntu"
   config.vm.box_url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/86m4h2r70mowtse/package.box?dl=0&raw=1

This is just XUbuntu with NVM, node, emberjs installed

I am going to try rebuilding the base box with NFS installed as per https://coderwall.com/p/uaohzg/use-nfs-to-speed-up-your-vagrant

Answer (score 1):

remove this line and try again.

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant/", type: "nfs"
```

Vagrant mounts current folder to vagrant box's /vagrant automatically

If you have to mount as NFS, then how about this?

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :nfs => { :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=777"] }
```

I did test with both NFS setting in Vagrant, but with different box image. Here is my test box:

```
  config.vm.box = "precise64"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/precise/current/precise-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box "
```

Maybe the problem is in that box image `box-cutter/ubuntu1404-desktop`

Comment: It needs to be NFS as we are using ember cli which chokes on the default file share strategy with the amount of watches it adds

Comment: Battery is about to die on my MB :p I'll give this a blast this evening - thank you

Comment: Do i need to install anything in the base box for this to work before I try and provision it?

Comment: I tried other box image, it is fine with nfs, could you please confirm the box `"box-cutter/ubuntu1404-desktop"` is good or not?

Comment: Hmmmm - I am now wondering if I need to install NFS on the base box... The base I am using is in my edit - I ommited it because it's a big base box and some people would already have box-cutter/ubuntu1404-desktop...

Comment: Confirmed your box works, mine still does not even after installing NFS and repackaging :/